# Worst case of nearest neighbor heuristic for symmetric TSP

Tags: greedy, traveling-salesman

I have implemented the nearest neighbor heuristic for solving symmetric TSP problems. I was wondering if there is any relation between the solution found by the heuristic and the optimal solution?

Can we state theoretically how much higher the route length is in a worst case scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The book "In pursuit of the Traveling Salesman" (Cook) mentions that: nearest neighbor will never do worse than `1 + log(n)/2` times the cost of the optimal (which in turn comes from some paper).

It's a great book, described the other construction heuristics too.

Comment: Do note that TSP is simple: it doesn't have many constraints, nor any difficult ones. In real world cases (VRP variants etc), the gap is far wider.

Comment: Does this also apply to symmetric TSP that NOT satisfy the triangle inequality?